# Xamarin Android emulator screen gets split into 4 identical rectangles when deploying

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, emulation

I've just gotten into developing apps for smartphones (I'm fairly adept with objective programming already and have some experience with Visual Studio) and decided to try out Xamarin. I've installed Xamarin Studio and Visual Studio 2015 Community with Xamarin without any problems. However, when I actually try to deploy the app (using the Xamarin Android API 15 emulator), a weird bug happens: the screen of the emulator gets split into 4 identical rectangles as you can see in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIXJy.jpg). The screen controls still work like they should and are in the default positions (the buttons are not on each of the 4 rectangles and in the normal position for a phone). I can unlock the emulator and launch apps like I would be able to on a correctly working emulator. I have all the prerequisites for Android API 15 [installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7Xmd.jpg). The app behaves similarly when I deploy it on the Xamarin Android API 21 emulator (all the prerequisites are installed). I am trying to deploy the blank Visual Studio 2015 Xamarin.Android app without any code changes.

Have you guys ever seen such a bug (or maybe a feature :) ) and do you know how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution if anyone has the same problem: editing the emulator in the AVD to Use Host GPU fixes the issue.